# Repository, Service layer and Query objects

Tags: repository, n-tier-architecture, service-layer

I'm trying to implement an N-tier architecture using repositories and service layer in asp.net mvc application.
A Service object can own multiple repositories to collect all data it needs using the same unit of work.
Controllers call only Service objects and don't know anything about repositories.

Repository example:

```
public class UsersRepository : IUsersRepository
{
     public IEnumerable<User> GetUsers(UsersQuery query)
     {
        ...
     }
}
```

UsersQuery objects incapsulates several options for querying Users, e.g:

```
public class UsersQuery
{
    public bool IncludeDeleted { get; set; }
    public Expression<Func<User, object>> OrderBy { get; set; }
    //Ans so on...
}
```

How should I for example pass dynamic OrderBy clause (and other options) to my repository? Of course, it is possible just to pass Query object through the service, but it seems to me not to be the true way, as producing overhead and violating the DRY principle.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.